# Paragraph Similar Pairs Dataset

Tags: data-request, language

I have been working on a project where I need to find whether two paragraphs convey the similar meaning. Same as [Quora Question Pairs on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs), but instead of questions, paragraphs. But I could not find any dataset for that. So I tried using Google Translate by taking a paragraph translating it into several layers of language and then finally translating back to English. So these two paragraphs are similar and then taking some random pairs as not similar. E.g. translating a paragraph from English to French, then from French to Spanish then from Spanish to English again. The problem is that these two paragraphs are so equal. So can you please link me to some dataset for this?